# after remote commits got reviewed, if I git rebase, should I push it with --force?

Tags: git, push, rebase

My pull requests(remote commits) have been reviewed with comments, so I want to keep those commits.

But when I run git rebase the git push, it need me use --force parameter to destroy those commits and replace them with new commit ID,

Or I can choose merge(from my remote branch to my rebased local branch), but that will generate several new commits with same commit message yet different commit id, seems quite redundant.

How do you handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this situation is delete the remote branch and push the new branch.

So if the branch is `feature/1234`:

```
git push origin :feature/1234 # delete remote
git push -u origin feature/1234 # push to origin
```

The reason I do this is that the organization I work for has force push disabled and forces commit squashing

Comment: thank you. What about the reviewer's comments attached to your commits you ever pushed? Are the comments vanished?